# Jackson deserialization specific getter turning off

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

What is the most simple way to tell the Jackson to not serialize a specific getter method? I only want to say explicit to one getter, because I have a custom, complex class, and all setter and getter should function, only one should not:

```
mapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.AUTO_DETECT_GETTERS, true);
```

So this is not the proper way. I need to tell that I don't want to use the getter in this class:

```
public static class EventRow implements Serializable, Cloneable, GRSerializable {
    public int x
    public int y
    public double z
    public String eventKeyValuesPacked; 

    //This getter should not be used, because there is no explicit setter
    //for    this, and also no public... And it is only unpack  
    //EventKeyValuesPacked so it would be multiple data...
    public KeyValue[] getEventKeyValues() {
       KeyValue[] kvs = DA_EventKey.unpackKeyValues(eventKeyValuesPacked);
       return kvs == null ? new KeyValue[0] : kvs;
   }
}
```

Is there any annotation or `SerializationConfig` option to make invisible the `getEventKeyValues()` getter method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an annotation for this: [`@JsonIgnore`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.0.1/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonIgnore.html).

```
@JsonIgnore
public KeyValue[] getEventKeyValues() {
...
```

If you don't want to use an annotation for this then you'll need to write a [custom serializer](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers).

Comment: Thanks, i found it some sec, but to be more weird: without annotation? Is there any other option? I dont want to write to this "@JsonIgnore
" EventRow class because it is used in many ways and don't want to  other ppl to see my messing, so any Serialization.config option or ...?:S

Answer (score 3):

> What is the most simple way to tell the Jackson to not serialize a specific getter method
>   ...
>   without annotation?

Without writing a customer serializer...

If directly annotating the field/property/getter/setter to be skipped is undesirable, another approach is to make use of [the Jackson Mix-In feature](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations).

Yet another approach for serialization only would be to make use of [the Jackson JSON Views feature](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews), though this too requires annotations in some capacity.

Answer (score 0):

I think this almost does it:

```java
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

Comment: Note that this is a DEserialization configuration option -- not used for serialization configurations.  Its intention is to not throw an exception in the case where the JSON includes an element without a matching property in the Java data structure being deserialized to.

Answer (score 0):

This may depend on Jackson version -- prior to 1.9, getters and setters were handled separately, so not auto-detecting getter would have been enough. But with 1.9 and beyond, setter/getter/field are all combined into logical property, which may allow Jackson to deduce existence of property from setter.

So what you probably need to do is to also disable setter detection. Other options already given would work as well, mix-in annotations being a common way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```java
objectMapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.AUTO_DETECT_GETTERS, false);
```